# Invalid syntax when trying to open file path?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I cant seem to figure out why I get and invalid syntax error when trying to open my downloads folder? Here's what I'm typing into a python shell:

cd c:\users\ryan\downloads

I get the error:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

and it highlights the "c" in "c:\"

any suggestions? 
Thanks,

Comment: There is no `cd` command in the Python shell. Change directories at the command line, or use [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir).

Answer (score 2):

`cd` is a shell command, not a Python statement. It should be run in a shell or command interpreter, not in the Python REPL.

Answer (score 2):

`cd whatever` is a fine command for e.g `cmd.exe`, but **not** for `python.exe` even when run as an interactive read-eval-print loop.

`import os` followed by a call to `os.chdir(whatever)` is more likely to do what you what within an interactive Python interpreter...